# Is it possible to be aware of exception occurrence by monitoring IDT?

Tags: windows, exception, kernel, usermode

Is it possible to be aware of exception occurrence (In user-mode & kernel-mode) by monitoring IDT(Interrupt Descriptor Table)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. However, actual implementation can only be done in *kernel mode*.

Monitoring a *hardware exception* requires a hook to an interrupt in *IDT*. This will need a write access to the *IDT*. In *Windows*, including any protected mode operating systems, it must be done in *kernel mode* using a *device driver*.

In *user mode*, it must be done with the help of a *device driver*, where exceptions are *reported* to the *user mode* application. So it's possible to monitor the exceptions indirectly in *user mode*. Meaning that the *user mode* application is not the one that actually monitors the exceptions.

Comment: You're right Jay, it has to be done with kernel privilages.So can we be aware of any exception accurrence in user-mode apps? or this procedure just inform us of exceptions or interrupts in a specific application?

Comment: Exceptions are global (any code, kernel and user modes). Software generated exception may or may not trigger an exception interupt.